# Modify JavaScript values after parsing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Aloha!

I'm working on a fairly interesting little project. To me, at least, this is interesting. Namely a Chrome extension. It gets links from a website and spits them out in a new tab. Basically, it's a Link Grabber, but it's very specific.

There are two URL schemes I have to deal with.

- https://example.org/s1/product/product-description-and-features-123456789
- https://example.org/s1/product/product-description-and-features-123456789?supplier=9876454

I have the following JSON generated: **EDIT**, after TJ Crowder's comment: It's not JSON. It's... **Edit II**: JavaScript. Thanks TJ.

```
(_chrome);
    !function() {
        for (var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a:link[href*='/s1/product/']:not([href*='#']):not([href^=javascript])"), links = new Array(elements.length), i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) links[i] = {
            host: elements[i].host,
            hostname: elements[i].hostname,
            href: elements[i].href,
            productnumber: elements[i].href,
            pathname: elements[i].pathname,
            search: elements[i].search,
            text: elements[i].text
        };
        console.log(links)
        _chrome2.default.runtime.sendMessage(links);
    }();
```

The issue comes up when I want to do the productnumber. For that, I would need to be able to modify elements[i].href in a function. From an earlier project, I have said function. I've already fidgeted around with it until I have hit the wall that led me to make this post.

```
function() {
                var urlsList = JSON.parse(elements[i].href);
                    console.log(urlsList);
                var ju = urlsList.split('?')[0]
                    pat = /[-|\/](\d{5,8})$/
                    rv = pat.exec(ju)
                    if (rv !== null) {
                                      console.log("Found id: " + rv[1])
                        return rv[1]}}
```

So my question is this: How do I isolate all the product numbers and split off everything after a potential "?"?

Cheers and thanks for the help!

Comment: *"I have the following JSON generated:"* That isn't, remotely, JSON...?

Comment: ... it's not? So what am I working with here? Basically, I'm modifying code here that some other dude at work gave me, I'm afraid. And I'm a pretty terrible coder. I can do some JavaScript and some Angular, but I barely understand what I'm reading here.

Comment: It's JavaScript code. [JSON](https://json.org/) is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i think he meant that the function generates the json output.

Comment: @FedeSc - It doesn't, though. It produces an array of objects.

Comment: 1) You already "split off everything after a potential "?"" by separating each URL into pathname, hostname, and search so . You can parse the individual parameters of `search` by using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API. 2) `JSON.parse(elements[i].href)` doesn't seem to make sense  because an URL isn't a JSON.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Agreed. Now that I know what I'm working with, this makes zero sense. I'm now reading up on JavaScript Source Code as suggested by T.J. Crowder. I suspect that a Replace might actually do the job. Maybe. I'm just trying things here and there.

Answer (score 0):

After @T.J. Crowder got me on the right track by suggesting that it's not JSON I'm working with, it was fairly easy.

```
productnumber: elements[i].href.replace(/.+?(\d{5,8})\?.+/,"$1"),
```

And that was it. Thanks, T.J.!